# linking .so files crash after dlsym

Tags: c, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I am having an libA.so and i want to use a function in that dynamic library.

I am loading the so using DLOPEN 
program_handle = dlopen(program_so, RTLD_NOW);
it does not give any error

i want to access a function "entry"
fnPtr is a function pointer having the same signature as that of entry
as mentioned in the header file.

*(void**)fnPtr= dlsym(program_handle, "entry");
here as well dlerror() doesnot show any error.

when i call
(*fnPtr)(args); **//GIVES ME A SEGMENTATION FAULT ON THIS LINE**

I am stuck at this point. Please let me know how to proceed.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Firstly, try debugging your program. Also, what is that cast to `void *` supposed to do in the assignment from `dlsym()`?

Comment: Also dont just check for dlerror() you could also check the return value (e.g the function pointer) for NULL. This because a call to dlerror will clear the error, hence you would have to store the return value if you want to do proper error handling when polling dlerror.

Comment: H2CO3: I am debugging the program using gdb, (void * ) is a just to typecast.

Comment: junix :   i am also checking the return value for NULL.